# Booking extra economy seat for comfort allowed on transatlantic budget airlines?

Tags: air-travel, budget

[Some airlines allow customers to book two economy seats for comfort](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052748703510204575085430741468758). Do budget transatlantic airlines like Wow and Norwegian allow this?

Comment: Have you checked their websites? Basic research first... *right?*

Comment: Some might, but it's important to check with the airline and follow their procedure (assuming they offer such a service) so the extra seat is marked properly in their computer system. Otherwise, you could end up with your extra seat filled by someone else because it was a no-show or you could wind up sitting in 5A with your extra seat chilling unhelpfully back in 21B.

Comment: I think you'll need to restrict your question to one airline at a time, currently there are multiple possible correct answers, which doesn't really fit the SE model, imho.  Voting to put on hold until edited.